# why the uilabel can put text at the left very beginning , but can't put text on the right end

Tags: ios, uilabel

just as the picture :

[image]

Blue background view is the UILabel , and we can see that the text begin very close to the label's left , but there will be some distance between the text and the label's right.can i set the label's text align the right as close as to the left ?

Comment: yourLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight, does the job

Comment: Set lbl.textAlignment = .justified or select justify align from attributes inspector

Comment: @Mamta thanks , set to justified is well work!

Comment: @Suresh thanks , set alignment to justified the is more correct answer:)